C# code uses System.Data.SqlClient and works on multiple servers, but how do I know what DRIVER to specify in connected Python code?
I am working on a large C# application. I am trying to connect the C# code to a small Python script for some very specific number crunching.
When the C# code executes the Python code, it passes along any necessary data as command-line arguments. In theory, these arguments include everything the Python code needs to connect to the SQL database to fetch more data as needed. (The connection-related arguments being passed are data source, initial catalog, username, and password. The other arguments are object ID, request ID, log file path, and logging level.)
The Python fetches the data using pyodbc and pandas. My connection string explicitly specifies the driver: DRIVER={SQL Server};.
In my initial testing, everything about this worked just fine. However, the C# application is installed on multiple servers, and it turns out some of them do not have SQL Server installed, which causes the Python code to crash the first time it tries to fetch data.
The C# code connects to the database using System.Data.SqlClient, so no driver name has to be explicitly specified anywhere.
Is there any way to resolve this? Is there either A) a way in C# to get the name of the appropriate driver at runtime so that it can be passed as an argument to the Python code or B) a way for the Python code to fetch data without specifying a driver, similar to what C# is doing?
For what it's worth, I have already tried changing the DRIVER specification to things like ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and SQL Server Native Client 11.0, but there does not seem to be one driver that is universally installed on every single server on which the C# app is installed, so inevitably the Python doesn't work somewhere, no matter what driver I specify.

In c# there is no driver (anything native that could be used from almost anything like ODBC) its all implemented in the managed code. Don't know Python to much but i would assume you have to distribute a fitting driver with your Python app.

Do you need to ensure that a sqlserver package and dependencies are installed on the new client? Perhaps like https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/
